Symbol name is not showing
When I create new symbol in KiCad Eeschema the symbol name isn't showing up, like in the picture. I saw in a video that it should. How to make it show up? I'm using Kicad 8.0, but I had this problem in version 7 too.


If you look closely at the linked Youtube video, you can see that PlumPot demonstrates using KiCad 5. Note that since V5, the Symbol Library format has changed and Versions 7 & 8 do not show the Symbol Name in the editor.
In V5 the "Symbol Name" was used as the Part Number of the component. In V7/8 that regime has changed and instead the "Value" field is commonly used to display the Part Number of an IC.
Therefore for your particular example, you would set the "Value" field to "bababa" and it would appear on the Symbol Editor.

Open the properties box for the component and, look at the visibility of the reference: -

Can you see the "Show" column and the tick boxes?
Try this and hopefully that'll be it.

No, this is happening when I edit the symbol in the symbol editor. If I do as you showed, the value is just "~". I have to manually type it in as opposed to it being there automatically like the video shows.

@Radar32 You don't have to type it in. It will be populated when the part is placed on the schematic. The default in the library editor is ~.
